# aiohttp stops sending after some time

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am writing some code that needs to send concurrent HTTP requests to some server
in case it gets an error, it should retry.
when I'm running it, I see fast sending and after several minutes the speed of the sending decreases to 0. it's like something gets locked and doesn't release and it just stops sending.

the function that sends the data is this

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def handle_line(self, line, destination):
    while True:
        response = yield from aiohttp.request('POST', destination,
                                              data=line,
                                              headers=headers,
                                              connector=self.tcp_conn)
        if response.status == 200:
            self._succeeded += 1
            if self._succeeded % 20000 == 0 and self._succeeded != 0:
                logger.debug("Sent {} events from file".format(self._succeeded))
                self.update_dynamo_counter(destination)
            break
        elif response.status != 200:
            logger.debug("Error sending data. Status: {}".format(response.status))
            continue
    return (yield from response.read())
```

the connector is being initialized with

```
tcp_conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=100)
```

the send function is being called by adding 800 tasks to a list and then waiting for them to avoid chocking up the  io

```
lines_to_send.append(asyncio.async(self.handle_line(json.dumps(data), destination)))
if len(lines_to_send) % 800 == 0:
    yield from asyncio.wait(lines_to_send)
    lines_to_send = []
```

I am having problem debugging it or even figuring out what the problem is.
anybody has a clue?

Comment: Would you publish full example? I don't saw issues like you mentioned but if I'll get reasonably small test which reproduces the issue I can debug it and figure out what's going on.

Comment: if I get 504 errors it becomes reproducable. I also noticed that the code completely gets stuck on epoll. I see it in strace. Process 26228 attached
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {8330, 766772926}) = 0
epoll_wait(7,

Comment: I believe it's a duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970740/python-aiohttp-request-stopped-but-raised-no-exception

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov I tried the solution in the link you post. it didn't solve it. now it gets infinite retries but it doesnt actually send or do anything

Comment: Would you attach a full example code that introduces your problem?

Comment: Have you tried closing the request? https://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientResponse.close

Comment: I've rewritten my code in nodejs but will try out of curiousity