# Python aiohttp request stopped but raised no exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I use `aiohttp` to request the url.  Most of the time it runs normally, but sometimes it stops without raising any exception.

As you can see in the code, I catch all the exceptions, but when it stops no log of exceptions is printed.

The logs look like:

```
get_live_league_games: while True
try
yield from aiohttp.request
```

but the '`res = yield from r.json()`' does not print, it stops and does not throw any exceptions.

```
while True:
    print('get_live_league_games: while True')
    start = time.clock()
    try:
        print('try')
        r = yield from aiohttp.request('GET',url)
        print('yield from aiohttp.request')
        res = yield from r.json()
        print('res = yield from r.json()')
    except aiohttp.errors.DisconnectedError as e:
        logging.warning('get_live_league_games:',e)
        yield from asyncio.sleep(10)
        continue
    except aiohttp.errors.ClientError as e:
        logging.warning('get_live_league_games:',e)
        yield from asyncio.sleep(10)
        continue
    except aiohttp.errors.HttpProcessingError as e:
         logging.warning('get_live_league_games:',e)
         yield from asyncio.sleep(10)
         continue
    except Exception as e:
         logging.warning('get_live_league_games,Exception:',e)
         yield from asyncio.sleep(10)
         continue
    print('request internet time : ', time.clock()-start)
    yield from asyncio.sleep(10)
```

Comment: unrelated: the code is very repetitive. You could drop all exception handlers except the last one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That *may* happen due internet nature -- connection may 'hang' for very long period before disconnection error raises.

That's why you usually need timeout for client http operations.

I suggest wrapping `aiohttp.request()` call into `asyncio.wait_for`.

Comment: Does the http's timeout parameter work ? will aiohttp throws timeout exception?

Comment: It seems that the code stops at `yield from r.json()`

Comment: `yield from r.json()` actually reads HTTP payload body so it's the most likely point for hanging

Comment: @Nianing what *http's timeout parameter* are you talking about? If you wrap `aiohttp.request()` into `asyncio.wait_for()` it will raise `asyncio.CancelledError` on timeout.

Comment: I mean that the `aiohttp.request()` has a parameter  that can be setted the time value, such as 10 secs. when time is up, the `aiohttp.request()` will throws a exception?

Comment: What's parameter name mentioned by you? We've dropped `timeout` parameter from `aiohttp.request` ages ago (about year and half) for sake of `asyncio.wait_for()`

Comment: ...oh,I see.thanks.`asyncio.wait_for()` solves my problem. Thanks again

Comment: `aiohttp.client.request()` does have a `timeout` parameter.  Why isn't that the recommended solution?  Is this answer outdated? https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/da2457463f75b559f39bbdef2276e97e1edde151/aiohttp/client.py#L999

Comment: `request()` has had not `timeout` argument in 2015. We have resurrected it later with different behavior.